# Removed sprite still seems to exist – cocos2D

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm making a little game with cocos2D where you can steer a ship with the accelerometer and shoot down things by tapping the screen. The things you shoot down are controlled by a CCMoveTo which moves them from top of the screen down to below 0. If the ship collides with one of the flying things they stop spawning and all other schedules are paused. A "pause screen" appears.

code:

```
for (CCSprite *sprite in _flyingObjects)
{
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(_ship.boundingBox, _sprite.boundingBox))
    {
        [sprite removeFromParentAndCleanUp:YES];
        [self pauseSchedulerAndActions];

        CCMenuItem *resumeMenuItem = [CCMenuItemImage itemWithNormalImage:@"resume.gif" selectedImage:@"resume.gif" target:self selector:@selector(resumeButtonTapped:)];
        resumeMenuItem.position = ccp(150, 190);
    }
}

- (void)resumeButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    [self removeChild:resumeMenuItem];
    [self resumeSchedulerAndActions];

}
```

The flying objects are generated randomly on the x-axis every 1 second on the same y-value.

My problem is that when the _ship collides with a flying object, the menu pops up with the resumeButton, and if I click the resumeButton it removes as it should but only for a 1/100 second, then the menu is loaded again.
It means that the `CGRectIntersecsRect()` detects collision even though I have `removeAndCleandUp` it before which should remove then and then when the resumeButton is clicked they should begin spawning at the top, not be invisible left and collide with the ship.  What is causing this?
Sorry for a bad formulated question, please ask if it's unclear. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`removeFromParentAndCleanUp:` removes node from its parent's `children` array, while you are enumerating `_flyingObjects` collection. You have to remove your sprite from `_flyingObjects` too.

Remember that you must not mutate a collection while enumerating it, so store objects which must be removed in temporary collection, and remove objects in this collection from `_flyingObjects` after you finish enumerating.

Comment: Actually you can mutate an array when you're enumerating backwards via [_flyingObjects reverseObjectEnumerator] and only delete the current object or any already enumerated one.